# Partially rendering ASP page because SQL is slowing it down

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have made an ASP.NET webpage. I'm looking for a way to render the page partialy because I have a gridview and a couple of dropdownlists I'm filling with SQL Data. This takes a very long time. So I would like the page to load all the "non SQL related stuff" first and then whenever the SQL is done the SQL related controls get added.

I've thought of using an UpdatePanel that gets loaded and then automatically gets triggered whenever the client has received the page on the screen.

This is the part of the .aspx page where I use the dropdownlists (which need SQL).

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <h3>
            Dienstregeling
        </h3>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Van: </span>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlVertrek" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"></asp:DropDownList>                   
        </div>                       

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">Naar: </span>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAankomst" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"></asp:DropDownList>                    
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The code behind:

```
    private void VulStations()
    {
        btnPlanReis.Enabled = false;
        //De dropdownlist aankomst vullen met de station namen
        StationService stationServ = new StationService();
        List<Station> stations = stationServ.GetAllStations();
        ddlAankomst.DataValueField = "station_id";
        ddlAankomst.DataTextField = "station_name";

        ddlVertrek.DataValueField = "station_id";
        ddlVertrek.DataTextField = "station_name";

        ddlAankomst.DataSource = stations;
        ddlAankomst.DataBind();
        ddlVertrek.DataSource = stations;
        ddlVertrek.DataBind();
        btnPlanReis.Enabled = true;
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        KlantService klantServ = new KlantService();
        Klant testKlant = klantServ.GetKlantByID(2);
        Session["userLogin"] = testKlant;
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            setDefaultTijdstip();
            setDefaultDatum();
        }
    }
```

Thanks